# Input a URL to an image and display it on the page in Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

For a project in HTML I need a button with add image displayed on it, this needs to open a textbox.

If you put a URL to an image into this, it needs to display the Image on the current page.

Is there any working examples or Jsfiddle to accomplish this? usin Javascript.

Comment: Use `prompt` to get the URL and once you got it assign it to image element.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Here we generally expect you to have a go at it yourself, and show us what you'e done so far, then we help you to make it work the way you wanted it to. In this case, I'd have expected you to show us an attempt at an html button.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var image = document.getElementById('image');

function getUrl() {
    var url = prompt('Enter image URL');
    
    if (url) { // Do string and URL validation here and also for image type
        return url;
    } else {
        return getUrl();
    }
}

image.src = getUrl();
```

```html
<img id="image"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a URL for the picture, you can simply use `prompt`. Once you've got the URL, what you want to do is load the image, check if it is really an image (an not just an .html document for example) and then display it.

```js
var img = new Image();
    img.src = prompt("Url of a picture:");
    
    // The URL isn't valid or the resource isn't a picture
    img.onerror = function() { alert("Provided URL does not point to a valid picture.") };
    
    // Ok, we have correct picture; display it
    img.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("yourImgElement").src = img.src;
    };
```

```html
<img id="yourImgElement">
```

Comment: How do I make sure that this only happens when a button is pushed?

Comment: Wrap that code into a function, then call the newly created function a `click` event happens. You can simply use `onClick` parameter on the button.